# how to cast Action<Derived> to Action<Base>

Tags: c#, delegates, as-operator

```
public class SettingsBase
{

}
public class SettingsDerived : SettingsBase
{

}
public class yyy
{
    public void StartUpMethod(Action<SettingsDerived> settings)
    {
        //something goes here..
        SettingsDerived ds = new SettingsDerived();
        settings(ds);//take out SettingsDerived properties..
        SettingsBase bs = Method1(settings as Action<SettingsBase>);//as operator returns null because settings is not of type Action<SettingsBase>
        //again do something on s based on extracted SettingsDerived

    }

    public SettingsBase Method1(Action<SettingsBase> settings)
    {
        SettingsBase s = new SettingsBase();
        //something goes here
        settings(s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

how do I achieve this? OR any work around?

Comment: Your code makes little to no sense without an example of its usage. Can you show the situation in which you're hoping this will work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, it doesn't make sense.

the settings action you pass to `StartUpMethod` is typed to Derived and will be entitled to use the interface of  `SettingsDerived`.   You can't then give it a base class and expect it to just handle it.

eg, if I have...

```
public class SettingsDerived : SettingsBase
{
   public string DerivedSetting { get; set; }
}
```

I'm entitled to do :-

```
y.StartUpMethod( a => a.DerivedSetting = "blah" );
```

but in the method1 you are trying to give it a `SettingsBase s = new SettingsBase();`

which won't have the `DerivedSetting`

Comment: I am using third party control(Devexpress ASP.NET MVC), whose settings goes like `SettingsBase`.. and I created a wrapper class for that control to have some additional settings which is my `SettingsDerived`.. `Method1` is nothing but I am invoking a method to get Control Settings.. and `StartUpMethod` is my wrapper class method which would invoke my wrapped control.. now could you please suggest me how do I achieve the same..

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: Keith is right; if you have a method that takes an Apple, you can't turn it into a method that takes a Fruit; the method takes an Apple but a method that takes a Fruit could be given an Orange. You can go the other way: if you have a method that takes a Fruit then you can turn it into a method that takes an Apple, because an Apple is a Fruit.