# Why can't I pass a lambda expression with a less-derived parameter type to a variable of type Action<T> given that the latter is contravariant on T?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates, contravariance

Let's say I have these classes:

```
class Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }
```

And then I declare a variable like this:

```
Action<Cat> c;
```

Now, [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-7.0) is contravariant on `T`, so I can do this:

```
void Foo(Animal a) { }
c = Foo;
```

That makes sense.  But when I do this, I get [compiler error CS16611](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1661?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1661)):

```
c = (Animal a) => { };
```

I can even do this with no error:

```
Action<Animal> b = (Animal a) => { };
c = b;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will boil down to the fact lambdas don't have a type and can only be implicitly cast to either exact delegate or expression tree...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to cast Action<Derived> to Action<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727706/how-to-cast-actionderived-to-actionbase)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: That's not entirely true as of C# 10 with its [Lambda expression improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#lambda-expression-improvements). Lambdas now may have a natural type.

Comment: The problem here is that the type argument is contravariant but the delegates themselves are invariant (there's no reference conversion), as explained in the flagged duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Super short version: you can tell the compiler which delegate type you want it to use for your expression using casting:

```
c = (Action<Animal>)(a => { });
```

---

Right, that aside..

As madreflection pointed out while I was writing this (thanks mad), the problem is that pure delegates are not contravariant. Contravariance works only for generic delegates of the same generic type.

Consider this list of items:

```
// Let's start with defining some delegate types:
delegate void AnimalAction(Animal parm);
delegate void MyAction<in T>(T parm);

// Now here are my variables, all working fine:
Action<Animal> actAnimal = (Animal a) => { };
MyAction<Animal> myAnimal = (Animal a) => { };
AnimalAction animalAction = (Animal a) => { };
```

They all look basically the same, and indeed are all functionally identical. Sadly no matter how similar they look, and no matter the fact that the method `void DoNothing(Animal parm) { }` can be assigned to all of them, the compiler will tell you that they're not the same.

So what happens when we have a lambda expression like `(Animal a) => { }`? Well all of the above will accept it because the compiler is bright enough to figure out what you're doing.

Now let's change it up:

```
// New delegate for cats
delegate void CatAction(Cat parm);

// New variables, but these all fail:
Action<Cat> actCat = (Animal a) => { };
MyAction<Cat> myCat = (Animal a) => { };
CatAction catAction = (Animal a) => { };
```

The compiler objects in all of these cases because it the transitional type of the lambda expression (`delegate _expression_type(Animal a)`) is not reference-convertable to the various target delegate types.

You can get around this in a few ways however. You can wrap one delegate in another of compatible type using `new Action<Cat>(some_animal_action)`. Or you can simply tell the compiler to make the right type from the beginning, like I put at the top.

So these all work:

```
c = (Action<Animal>)(a => { });
c = new Action<Animal>(a => { });
c = new Action<Animal>((Animal a) => { });
```

(But don't do the `new` versions, it will probably create a nested delegate.)

Oddly, you can also capture the output in an auto-typed variable using `var`. This works because the compiler knows to use `Action<...>` and `Func<...>` for expression delegates, but only when the delegate's type is not fully specified beforehand. So this works too:

```
var temp = (Animal a) => { };

// 'temp' is of type Actions<Animal> so this works:
c = temp;
```